# cakephp create new field if not present in a table

Tags: php, mysql, database, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I do google but not found any proper solution to create a new field if not field.

For example : if I have to add a field according to the title which is in any other language.
`title`, `title_eng`, `title_fr` ... etc

I found solution in `php` but looking for a solution which is in `cakephp`

```
$languageData = $this->LanguageSetting->find('first', array('conditions' => array('id' => $post['language_id'])));

                $short_name = $languageData['LanguageSetting']['short_name'];
                $subjectfieldName = "email_subject_" . $short_name;
                $contentfieldName = "email_template_" . $short_name;

                //add subject field if not present
                $subjectfield = $this->LanguageSetting->query("SELECT $subjectfieldName FROM email_managers");
                if (!$subjectfield) {
                    $insert_col = "ALTER TABLE email_managers ADD " . $subjectfieldName . " VARCHAR(255) NULL";
                }

                //add template field if not present
                $contentfield = $this->LanguageSetting->query("SELECT $contentfieldName FROM email_managers");
                if (!$contentfield) {
                    $insert_col = "ALTER TABLE email_managers ADD " . $contentfieldName . " TEXT NULL";
                }
```

I tried above solution but getting this error.

> Database Error
>
> Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
>   'email_subject_' in 'field list'

Comment: Really? Improve your Google skills: https://www.google.com/search?q=cakephp+2+translations&oq=cakephp+2+translations First hit.

Comment: I didn't want translations. I want to add columns

Comment: "*if I have to add a field according to the title which is in any other language*" - This is not translations? However, your approach to this is a pretty bad one for multiple reasons. Check the behavior.

Comment: @burzum Yes ,I know that. But can you please guide me how can I do that.

Answer (score -1):

This might help you.

```
$columns = $this->LanguageSetting->query('show columns from email_managers');
                $exists = FALSE;
                foreach ($columns as $fields) {
                    if ($fields['COLUMNS']['Field'] == $subjectfieldName) {
                        $exists = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (!$exists) {
                    $this->LanguageSetting->query("ALTER TABLE email_managers ADD " . $subjectfieldName . " VARCHAR(255) NULL");
                }
```